# Volcado a bbdd SQL Server del contenido en imágenes de un input type file

Tags: javascript, sql, html5, input-type

voy muy perdido con una parte de mi proyecto. Agradecería comentarios, ayudas y ejemplos. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Tengo un proyecto web donde ya almaceno datos del form en la bbdd mediante el uso de Store procedures.

He querido añadir un nueva funcionabilidad donde arrastrando imágenes, las visualice durante la carga visual a la página y al guardar los datos, volcar dichas imágenes en la bbdd en SQL Server.  En concreto será un artículo relacionado con varias imágenes en una relación 1:M.

Mediante el código js que anexo, consigo visualizar en la web las imágenes que arrastro al crear el html que también anexo.

**image-uploader.js**

```js
/*! Image Uploader - v1.2.3 - 26/11/2019
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Christian Bayer; Licensed MIT */

(function ($) {

    $.fn.imageUploader = function (options) {

        
        // Default settings
        let defaults = {
            preloaded: [],
            imagesInputName: 'images',
            preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
            label: 'Arrastra y suelta aqui las imagenes o click para abrir el buscador',
            extensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg'],
            mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
            maxSize: undefined,
            maxFiles: undefined,
        };

        // Get instance
        let plugin = this;

        // Will keep the files
        let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

        // The file input
        let $input;

        // Set empty settings
        plugin.settings = {};

        // Plugin constructor
        plugin.init = function () {

            // Define settings
            plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

            // Run through the elements
            plugin.each(function (i, wrapper) {

                // Create the container
                let $container = createContainer();

                // Append the container to the wrapper
                $(wrapper).append($container);

                // Set some bindings
                $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

                // If there are preloaded images
                if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

                    // Change style
                    $container.addClass('has-files');

                    // Get the upload images container
                    let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

                    // Set preloaded images preview
                    for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
                        $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
                    }
                }

            });

        };

        let createContainer = function () {

            // Create the image uploader container
            let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'image-uploader'});

            
            // Create the input type file and append it to the container
            $input = $('<input>', {
                type: 'file',
                id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName,
                name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
                accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
                multiple: ''
            }).appendTo($container);
            

            // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container #divInputFile
            let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the text container and append it to the container
                $textContainer = $('<div>', {class: 'upload-text'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the icon and append it to the text container
                $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-cloud-upload'}).appendTo($textContainer),

                // Create the text and append it to the text container
                $span = $('<span>', {text: plugin.settings.label}).appendTo($textContainer);


            // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
            $container.on('click', function (e) {
                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);
                // Trigger input click
                $input.trigger('click');
            });

            // Stop propagation on input click
            $input.on("click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Listen to input files changed
            $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

            return $container;
        };


        let prevent = function (e) {
            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };

        let createImg = function (src, id, preloaded) {

            // Create the upladed image container
            let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded-image'}),

                // Create the img tag
                $img = $('<img>', {src: src}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete button
                $button = $('<button>', {class: 'delete-image'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete icon
                $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-close'}).appendTo($button);

            // If the image is preloaded
            if (preloaded) {

                // Set a identifier
                $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

                // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
                let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
                    value: id
                }).appendTo($container)

            } else {

                // Set the index
                $container.attr('data-index', id);

            }

            // Stop propagation on click
            $container.on("click", function (e) {
                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);
            });

            // Set delete action
            $button.on("click", function (e) {

                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);

                // Get the parent element
                let $parent = $container.parent();

                // If is not a preloaded image
                if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

                    // Remove from preloaded array
                    plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function (p) {
                        return p.id !== id;
                    });

                } else {

                    // Get the image index
                    let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

                    // Update other indexes
                    $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function (i, cont) {
                        if (i > index) {
                            $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
                        }
                    });

                    // Remove the file from input
                    dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

                    // Update input files
                    $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
                }

                // Remove this image from the container
                $container.remove();

                // If there is no more uploaded files
                if (!$parent.children().length) {

                    // Remove the 'has-files' class
                    $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

                }

            });

            return $container;
        };

        let fileDragHover = function (e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Change the container style
            if (e.type === "dragover") {
                $(this).addClass('drag-over');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
            }
        };

        let fileSelectHandler = function (e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Get the jQuery element instance
            let $container = $(this);

            // Get the files as an array of files
            let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

            // Will keep only the valid files
            let validFiles = [];

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function (i, file) {
                // Run the validations
                if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
                    return;
                }
                validFiles.push(file);
            });

            // If there is at least one valid file
            if (validFiles.length) {
                // Change the container style
                $container.removeClass('drag-over');

                // Makes the upload
                setPreview($container, validFiles);
            } else {

                // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
                $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

            }
        };

        let validateExtension = function (file) {

            if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
                alert('El fichero de imagen "${file.name}" no tiene la extension permitida para ser almacenado: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join(', ')}"');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMIME = function (file) {

            if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
                alert('El fichero de imagen "${file.name}" no tiene la extension permitida para ser almacenado: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join(', ')}"');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMaxSize = function (file) {

            if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
                alert('La imagen "${file.name}" excede el tamaño maximo de ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb');

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let validateMaxFiles = function (index, file) {

            if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
                alert('La imagen "${file.name}" no es posible almacenarla por exceder el limite de imagenes de ${plugin.settings.maxFiles}');

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let setPreview = function ($container, files) {

            // Add the 'has-files' class
            $container.addClass('has-files');

            // Get the upload images container
            let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

                // Get the files input
                $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function (i, file) {

                // Add it to data transfer
                dataTransfer.items.add(file);

                // Set preview
                $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

            });

            // Update input files
            $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

        };

        // Generate a random id
        let random = function () {
            return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        };

        this.init();

        // Return the instance
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Y me crea este html que anexo en la parte que crea este js
**HTML**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visualizándose así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda y donde estoy atascado varios días sin conocer cómo poder hacerlo es: ¿Cómo puedo volcar a una tabla la referencia a las imágenes cargadas en el input type file con su clave ajena al artículo que representan?

Espero haber sido claro.
Agradecería referencias a ejemplos donde basarme o sugerencias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Guardar la imagen completa en la BD n o es aconsejable, lo que tendrías que hacer es guardar el nombre de la imagen o su url. Lógicamente el envío a la BD la harías con el php que te gestione los datos del formulario.

Comment: claro, está muy claro. Me gusta el riesgo